# Help determining power and energy of various signals

Tags: power, signal, energy

I need a bit of help. 
My problem is to determine the energy and power of each of the following signals:

```
A) x(t)=3e^(-10t)  ,t>0
B) x(t)=10cos(100πt)
C) x(t)=3e^(-10t)  cos(2πt),    0<t<1
```

Update:
A) 
[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Hi Danny, welcome to the Electrical Engineering Forums on Stack Exange.  Although questions like these, which come off as homework, are welcome here you need to give insight as to what you have already accomplished yourself or details on what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Good luck. If the question didn't say anything about the units of x, I'm not sure how I could answer this either.

Comment: I do not know resolve these exercises. I read a lot and do not understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the energy you have have to integrate the squared function.
To get the power you have to calculate the average of the energy from minus infinity to plus infinity.

Some properties to check your calculations:

- The energy of signal with finite power will be infinite.
- In case the energy is finite the power will be zero.
- Energy signals are limited in time.

Comment: This is a good example of how to answer a homework question. +1

Comment: Bro, help me to get these exercises, please.

Comment: Anyone that helps me , please. B and C exercises, please ;(